# Dynamically load a list of images based on server response

Tags: android

I am sending a request to a server and the server sends a list of appliance names. I want to load images based on the appliance names returned by the server, right now the server has 200 types of appliance names, and the server returns a list of random appliance name each time I send a request. Is there an efficient way to load images based on the response server.
Any help is appreciated.
the response is as follows:

"appliance":

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "type": "electronic",
    "make": "2015",
    "model": "2011",
    "serialNumber": "19218hdyew",
    "serviceTagNumber": "hfh251663",
    "name": "fridge"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "type": "electronic",
    "make": "2015",
    "model": "2011",
    "serialNumber": "19218hdyew",
    "serviceTagNumber": "hfh251663",
    "name": "coffee"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "type": "electronic",
    "make": "2015",
    "model": "2011",
    "serialNumber": "19218hdyew",
    "serviceTagNumber": "hfh251663",
    "name": "washing machine"
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "type": "electronic",
    "make": "2015",
    "model": "2011",
    "serialNumber": "19218hdyew",
    "serviceTagNumber": "hfh251663",
    "name": "fan"
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "type": "electronic",
    "make": "2015",
    "model": "2011",
    "serialNumber": "19218hdyew",
    "serviceTagNumber": "hfh251663",
    "name": "tv"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is returning image names, then you should create a method like

```
displayimage(String imagename)
```

where imagename is string you are getting from server.

In *`displayimage`* method you can use **setimageresource**

Comment: the server is not returning any image, it just returns image names.

Comment: Also i want to use images from R.drawable

Comment: how do i load an image when the appliance name is "washing machine"  R.drawable.washing maching is not a valid drawable resource because space is not allowed for resources.

Comment: first of all u have to make method that trims string values coming from server, then use this trimmed string in displayimage method

Comment: @dhaminipoornachandra Is it necessary that the images should be in drawable folder?. If you have no issues in keeping the images in assets folder, then you can try my code.

Comment: @KarandeepAtwal It should be fine to use from assets as well. Could you please send the code?

Comment: @dhaminipoornachandra It was me who commented above. If you can move the code to assets folder. Try my code in the answer. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all fetch response from server and parse it. Refer [volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) or [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) for more details.

After getting response from server, fetch imageUrl from it and perform lazy loading. Refer [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco), [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

To get imageUrl you need to concat imageName with your server url where actual image is located or tell your API developer to give full URL of image in webservice.

you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/lazy-load-of-images-in-listview) thread for Lazy loading

Comment: The server is not returning any URL.

Comment: Then you need to ask them to provide url if you want to load it from server.

Answer (score 0):

**Used the Android Universal Image-Loader This is best**

> Declare

```
    private ImageLoader imageLoader1;
```

> On Create

```
 imageLoader1 = ImageLoader.getInstance();

 imageLoader1.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getActivity()));
```

> no_image here a drawable image without any image load in Cache

```
   DisplayImageOptions
            options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.no_image) // resource or drawable
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.no_image) // resource or drawable
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.no_image)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .build();

    imageLoader1.displayImage(yourpath.replace(" ", "%20"), ivprofile, options);
```

Use Also It's dependency

with jar

```
  compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.5.jar')
```

and

```
  compile  'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.1'
```

**You Can Use Piccaso Also and Glide also**

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the images from drawable according to the server response. If you have the option to keep the images in assets folder,

then here is the solution,

1. Move your images to assets folder.
2. Then try the below code.

   ```
   AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
   InputStream inputStream = null;

   try {
       inputStream = assetManager.open(imageName + ".extension");
   }    
   catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } 

   if (inputStream != null) {
       Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
       imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
   }
   ```